# Flutter | how to add custom Icons in Mapbox's markers/symbol

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I was wondering how one could use his own icons in a Flutter-Mapbox plugins' marker?

There's no default marker icon (no provided icon - no marker),
and there's not enough documentation on how to use a custom image.

adding a symbol (marker) is as follows:

```
mapController.addSymbol(
      SymbolOptions(
           geometry:LatLng(0.0, 0.0), // location is 0.0 on purpose for this example
           iconImage: "pin"
         )
      );
```

whereas the `IconImage`, a String,  is the field which should contain the data about the icon (obviously), but the given [example repository](https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/lib/place_symbol.dart#L75) doesn't clarify the needed parameters (url, path etc.).

Providing a path to the assets doesn't work (unlike other widgets). In the example, they provide the IconImage field the value `airport-15`, and when running the app, it actually works, but I can't seem to find the resources' location (it's not in @drawables or my assets folder, or any other place in the project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom style on using `MapBox Studio`.

1. Create a new dataset if not already exist
2. Create tileset
3. Create new style & select `customize basic template`
4. Create new layer, give it a name for example `my_sym` and add newly created datasource
5. Then click on type & change it to symbol
6. Now click on `my_sym` two times. (first one will close the option menu & second one will open a new menu with symbol properties
7. Click on `icon` tab & select new icon. You can also upload your own svg icon.
8. Click on publish
9. Click on share it will show you the urls.
10. Copy the type of url & set `styleString` property.

For more info follow steps here
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-1/

API reference:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Answer (score 3):

As of release 0.0.5 it will be possible to load custom icon images for your markers. The idea is to add the icon image to your assets folder (for example: `assets/symbols/custom-icon.png`). If you specify this image as an asset in your pubspec.yaml and set the `iconImage` in the `SymbolOptions` to this path it will be loaded automatically.

Regarding the `airport-15`, this is an icon provided by the Android implementation of the plugin. It is part of the Maki Icons used in Mapbox. Because these icons are part of the Android implementation you will not find as a Flutter asset or an Android resource of the example app.

Comment: Hi, I am trying your answer in my web poject or PWA project of flutter.. I hav added ```assets/symbols/marker.png``` inside pubspec.yaml and then set it like this ``` iconImage: "assets/symbols/marker.png",``` but it doesn't show up in the maps.. is there something that I should add more?

Comment: @Timothy Sealy what if I want to add multiple markers which show price info? For example for booking an Hotel.